# Export Mobile Connect contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I need to do a complete export of all the mobile connect contacts in a Marketing Cloud account.
Currently, I'm doing a SELECT on the _MobileAddress data view, and then export the resulting data extension. 
But, that data view does not contain the contact key column. Which I need for my export. I wonder if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here:

**1. Mobile Connect lists**

Simply create a filtered list in Mobile Connect and export it - the Subscriber Key will be there.

---

**2. New Mobile Connect attribute**

- extend the Mobile Connect attribute set with a new custom value that represents the contact key
- create a new query that will pass your contact key value into two columns of a data extension
- configure a new import definition that will populate both the standard contact key and you new custom duplicate contact key column
- grab the new column with you _MobileAddress query